# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation only on android

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I making a react-native app, everything work **perfectly** on ios until i run it on android, i get this error

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

I still get the data, but i don't know why i can't login, here is the code:

```js
export default function Login(props: LoginI) {
  const user = useRef<User>();

  const [userExist, setUserExist] = useState<boolean>(false);
  let ListUser: any[] = [];
  const token = useSelector(
    (item: RootState) => item.persistedReducer.firebase.token
  );
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
  const {} = props;
  const addNew = () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(user.current?.user?.email)
      .set({
        userInfo: { ...user.current },
        note: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(),
      });
    // .then(() => console.log("success"));
  };
  const getUser = async () => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .get()
      .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((snapshot) => {
          ListUser.push(snapshot.id);
        });
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.current) {
      getUser();
    }
  }, [ListUser]);
  async function signIn() {
    // Get the users ID token
    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    user.current = userInfo;
    await getUser();
    console.log(ListUser.includes(user.current.user?.email));
    if (ListUser.includes(user.current.user?.email)) {
      dispatch(
        signedIn({ token: userInfo?.idToken, userInfomation: userInfo.user })
      );
    } else {
      addNew();
      dispatch(
        signedIn({ token: userInfo?.idToken, userInfomation: userInfo.user })
      );
    }
    // ListUser = ListUser.concat(user.current.user?.email);

    // console.log(ListUser.includes(user.current.user?.email));
    // addNew();
    dispatch(
      signedIn({ token: userInfo?.idToken, userInfomation: userInfo.user })
    );

    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      userInfo.idToken
    );

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          signIn();
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Login</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I still don't know how , it worked before, when i change `if request.auth != null;` to `if request.auth.uid != null;`
Here is the rule of firebase:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now it got error id 1, what going on ???????? Please help, thank you a lots

Answer (score 0):

The ‘**Permission denied**’ error that you are getting is due to **the rules that your database is currently having.**

When you want to allow access only to the users that are authenticated to perform operations in your database. The rules should look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
     }
   }
}
```

However, if you need a more granular set of rules, for instance, **to allow only the authenticated users, who have the value of the UID equal to the value of UID that comes from to authentication process, to be able to write to their own document**, then you should consider using the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /users/{uid} {
        allow create: if request.auth != null;
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && 
request.auth.uid == uid;
     }
   }
  }
```

You may refer to this [documentation](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) also. Alternatively, you may also have a look on the [GitHub link](https://gist.github.com/codediodeio/6dbce1305b9556c2136492522e2100f6).

Comment: If my answer was useful you can accept ✔ and upvote  :) Feel free to ask further queries.